# ASP.NET Detect if Javascript disabled field

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am hoping there is an answer for this...

**Setup:**
Pretty complex ASP.NET Application doing a bunch of user interaction, some of which requires that Javascript disables some fields when others are clicked (had to do it in Javascript, b/c the postback issues in ASP.NET made it impossible, so had to it client side).

That code is all well where Javascript does the classic 
   document.getElementById(currObj).disabled = true;

**The problem:**
When I am ready to submit the page, how can I make ASP.NET (C#) notice if a field (Textbox or Radio box) has been disabled client side, so it does NOT submit that field in the form?
Is this even possible?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Disabled fields are automatically **not** submitted in a form. Can't you check the `.Enabled` property in C#? I forget if setting it with the client will actually propagate to the server (I'm guessing it won't). Anyways, you could always set a hidden variable's value as the ID of a control when it is disabled - then check that value on the server. You could also check to see if the ID is in the posted querystring (as opposed to using `Textbox1.Enabled`) - it will be there only if it was not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Any disabled fields don't submit but normal and even hidden ones do. This is how disabled fields work.

```
<input type="text" name="Test_1" value="off" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" name="Test_2" value="on" />
<input type="hidden" name="Hidden_1" value="hide_off" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="hidden" name="Hidden_2" value="hide" />
```

In the example only `Test_2` and `Hidden_2` will submit because the others are disabled.

You can see it at work in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bJ7Rq

Comment: Hmm.. Asp.net doesn't seem to care they are disabled(or is it that it doesn't notice b/c Javascript makes the change without a postback), that's my point, it submits them even though javascript disabled it.

Comment: @WinFiddle If ASP doesn't use a simple form submit (which would honor the disabled status) then it is more backwards than I thought.

Comment: @TheZ: Pretty sure that information (disabled state, etc) is coming out of the ViewState, not the form itself. If you use Request.Form, it'll look like any other sane framework, not including the disabled inputs ;) (IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

The only way ASP.NET knows that a control has been disabled is if it was disabled from .NET and the `Enabled = false` property has been written to ViewState. When you disable a field on the client-side, this isn't the case, so ASP.NET will retain the default `Enabled` value.

As previous commenters have mentioned, the value of a disabled field will be completely excluded from the POST body sent to the server on postback. In the case of a basic `TextBox` on a page, that would mean the `Text` property would revert to `String.Empty`. To differentiate between an empty string in an enabled field and an actual disabled field, I think you'd need to look directly at the `Request.Form` object to see if the key exists. For example, if I had a `TextBox` named `myTextBox` on a blank page, `Request.Form["myTextBox"]` would be `null` for a disabled field. For an enabled field, it'd be whatever string value the field contained, including `String.Empty` if it were blank. Of course, if the control is in a naming container (e.g., a `ContentPlaceholder` or something) that messes with the `name` property on the actual field in HTML, you'd need to use the full HTML `name`.

So for example:

```
bool fieldIsEnabled = Request.Form["myTextBox"] == null;
```

It's not elegant, but it should get the job done (excluding checkboxes, which would also be `null` if the box wasn't checked).

Comment: Ah the good old Request.Form from old ASP days, I forgot that still works for .NET framework... very interesting approach, thank you George!

Comment: You're welcome! If this is the solution you ended up with, feel free to accept this answer for future readers. And if you found something better, please share that instead. :)